# Organize States and Cities and display certain way PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have this code that is suppose to display $fstate and then under it display all the $fcity's.  It display $fcity 3 times, then makes a new column.  My issue is I can get the states and cities to display, but I can't get the cities to display under the appropriate state.  Right now it displays all the states, then displays the cities under it.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$fquery = "SELECT state, city, count(city) as num FROM needs WHERE country='$usercountry' AND status='posted' GROUP BY state, city ORDER BY state, city";
if ($result = mysql_query($fquery)) {
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo "<table>";
    $i = 1;
    $cols = 3;
$prev = "";

    while ($frows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $fcity = $frows['city'];
        $fstate = $frows['state'];
        $fcitycount = $frows['num'];  // num is holding your count by city

if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "<tr>$fstate</tr><tr>";
$prev="$fstate";
}

        echo "<td><a href='node/browseresults.php?city=$fcity&state=$fstate'>$fcity, $fstate ($fcitycount)</a> </td>";
echo ($i < $num_rows) ? ((($i % $cols) == 0) ? '</tr>' : '') : '';
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

This is what I get right now (example):

```
ARMOSCTNTX

Brookland, AR (1)   Fayetteville , AR (2)   Harrisburg, AR (2)
Hot Springs, AR (1) Jonesboro, AR (1)   Searcy, AR (2)
St Louis, MO (3)
murrells inlet, SC (1)  Myrtle Beach, SC (1)
Memphis, TN (1)
Arlington, TX (1)
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
AR
Brookland, AR (1)   Fayetteville , AR (2)   Harrisburg, AR (2)
Hot Springs, AR (1) Jonesboro, AR (1)   Searcy, AR (2)

MO
St Louis, MO (3)

SC
murrells inlet, SC (1)  Myrtle Beach, SC (1)

TN
Memphis, TN (1)

TX
Arlington, TX (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "<tr>$fstate</tr><tr>";
```

You're producing a badly-formatted table. If your table contents aren't inside `<td>` or `<th>` tags, when it's rendered, they appear in the wrong place. Try this:

```
if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "<tr><th>$fstate</th></tr><tr>";
```

Comment: It worked but now the states are kind of tabbed over/indented...is there a way to make them align left?

Comment: @user2362601 - a `<th>` tag puts them in bold and centers them; try using `<td>` ones instead.

Comment: No problem - glad to have helped.